# Using CSS to Create Vertically Oriented Table

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-2

Our project needs to have a "table" with headers on the left hand side, at the beginning of each row, and then each object will be added to a column in the "table"

We also are trying to keep the project AJAXy, so we need to have edit in place functionality for this grid. We're using ASP.NET MVC 2, so I've been using PartialViews to replace table rows with editable rows as needed, but that obviously won't work for a vertically oriented table.

I tried setting it up using unordered lists and floating them, but my problem is that they don't seem to want to obey the overflow css tag.

**Current CSS**

```
.vertical-list-container {float:left; overflow-x:scroll}
.vertical-list {float-left;}
```

**HTML (changed to make it easer to follow)**

```
<ul class="vertical-list" id="table-header">
  <li>Id</li>
  <li>Name</li>
  <li>Address</li>
</ul>
<div class="vertical-list-container">
  <ul class="vertical-list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>John Doe</li>
    <li>123 Address Lane</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="vertical-list">
    <li>2</li>
    <li>Jane Doe</li>
    <li>456 Another Road</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What's expected is that if the two `vertical-lists` end up wider than `vertical-list-container` then there would be a horizontal scroll bar. What ends up happening though is each item that doesn't fit gets pushed down below, which means it doesn't line up with the "table" headers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an explicit width declaration to your `vertical-list-container` and `vertical-list` containers.  These can be relative (em, %) or fixed (px).

That will get the `vertical-list-container` to start obeying the overflow rule.

**Edit**

So the widths alone don't cut it.  You can get it to work by adding one extra element inside the vertical-list-container.  Then you can use some Javascript to set its width on load to:

```
number of columns * column width
```

See it [in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/gGaXj/).

Out of curiosity, why aren't you using a `<table>` for this?  It's tabular data and would be a valid (and easier) way to get it done.

Comment: I tried this but it still doesn't seem to work. Each list just gets pushed further down the page

Comment: Hmmm, you're right - I played around with it and found a way to do it.  See my edits for details.

Comment: There are a very large number of fields, that need to be compared side by side. Also, the items need to be editable in place. A table makes a vertical orientation like this difficult to do, so I opted for unordered lists so that I can do a full replace with an editable version.